# Today Updating problem

Tags: updates, 22.04, ubuntu-studio

I use Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS.

Today, Saturday, Aug. 13th 2022, I got the following problem:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the updating process started so fine, but... It suddenly stopped and shows the error message.

It has happened more than 3 times, today.

Why?

Is there a way to avoid it, or fix it?

It is after the full OS upgrade from 20.04.2 to 22.04.1.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. Copy the complete input and output of both into your question (copy/paste, not screenshots please).

Comment: Curiously, today, Ag. 15th, the problem isn't here. Maybe, it was fixed by the team. I don't know.